# How to keep the sidebars of table scrolling

Tags: css

I have three tables in my website the middle table,right side table and a left side table. when the content of the middle table increases it becomes scrollable but I am not able to make the sidebars also scrollable. How to do it using html and css?
the website url is: http://www.bestindiacollege.com

Comment: Please create a code snippet with your problem.

Answer (score -1):

the simple answer unfortunately is don't use tables for layout, your html/css is a mess of table/tr/td's and could be easily done with just divs and css. i know this isn't the most helpful advice but i would take some time to learn to make layouts with CSS

Comment: This should be a comment.